# How to convert oracle procedure into mysql with exception handling

Tags: mysql

**Hi all,**

Am new to mysql.Actually am oracle developer now am converting some procedure from oracle to mysql.In those changes I have doubt in Mysql.

In Oracle:-

```
Create procudure test_proc(p_id in varchar2,
p_error_code out number,
p_error_msg out varchar2) is
begin
insert into test_1(a) values(p_id);
commit;
p_error_code:=0;
exception when others then
p_error_code:=1;
p_error_msg:=substr(sqlerrm,1,150);
rollback;
return;
end;
```

I need same type of procedure in mysql or sample procedure how to handle exception and show it error as output variable like sqlerrm in oracle.

Thanks and regards,
vinoth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EXIT and CONTINUE Handler. But you cant get clear error details as you get in ORACLE.